# XPath - Parsing inside Attribute Values

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

The question is probably very easy for most to answer, since I am a complete beginner.

I have an attribute value in an XML that contains several pieces of information that are separated by a separator.
Now I want to read only one specific information out of the attribute.

Heres an Example:

```
<Product DueDate="" FinishedTrimHeight="" FinishedTrimWidth="" ID="" Name="" Notes="1000 | ST | 170ma | 4/4 | 135ma | 4/4 | F-EB-4S DBK-16S | BNDLI | SaddleStitch | Links | Sped" RequiredQuantity="" TextContentFile="" Type=""> </Product>
```

I want to extract only "170ma" out of the Attribute in this case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what have you tried, which XPath version do you use, what are the criteria to select that values (third item after tokenization by `|`?)?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Currently using Version 2.0 in Oxygen (can be any though), and basicly yes, it is whatever item after a certain count of |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
tokenize(Product/@Notes, ' \| ')[3]
```

I say "something like" because you did not post your attempt and it's not clear from which context you need this.

Requires XSLT 2.0 or higher.